# The given name of the entity "ClassName" is empty

Tags: eclipse, jpa

I am using JPA in Eclipse (Kepler) and my Entity Beans will occasionally start showing errors although nothing has changed in the class.

Suddenly the `@Entity` annotation is highlighted as an error and the associated error message is:

> The given name of the entity "com.test.domain.Result" is empty.

If I specifically add the name attribute (i.e. `@Entity(name="somename")` then the "somename" part of the line is highlighted as an error.

Cleaning the project, restarting Eclipse does not fix this. I can copy the classes into a new project and not get the error for a while, but once it appears (with no apparent cause) I cannot get rid of it.

Any ideas what is causing it and how I can fix it please?

---

**Update:**

Well, I can find in the project properties a facility to specifically set this error to warning (or ignore!) (Project Properties -> JPA -> Errors/Warnings -> Type "Entity Name is Empty" (2nd one down in the list). Everything works fine if I do this, however I am still wondering what is causing the error in the first place.

Comment: Update: Well I can find in the project properties a facility to specifically set this error to warning (or ignore!) (Project Properties -> JPA -> Errors/Warnings -> Type "Entity Name is Empty" (2nd one down in the list). Everything works fine if I do this however I am still wondering what is causing the error in the first place

Comment: Are you using JBoss Tools with the Hibernate platform specified for JPA Platform?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, yes I was. I think it was Eclipse just getting confused

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can find in the project properties a facility to specifically set this error to warning (or ignore!) (Project Properties -> JPA -> Errors/Warnings -> Type "Entity Name is Empty" (2nd one down in the list.

Unsetting this later actually doesn't cause the error to return, I am guessing eclipse gets out of sync with itself.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem in my project. My app deploy without errors in my app server... it seems to be a validation bug. I removed JPA facet from 'Project properties -> Project facets'. You could turn off 'JPA validation' instead.

Answer (score 4):

It is an issue with Eclipse JPA Validator not recognizing `@ElementCollection`, if I remove this annotation all 21 errors are gone from eclipse, I removed because I do not need it anymore, have replaced it with an entity.

Answer (score 2):

did you tried to adjust the JPA version ?
I had this issue, I had Hibernate JPA 2.0 in my pom and the project Facet was configured to point to JPA 2.1 so I just changed this to be JPA 2.0 in the project Facet.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the errors went away when I switched the "Platform" (Project properties - JPA) from "Hibernate 2.1" to "EclipseLink 2.5.x". Obviously the JPA validator had trouble validating via Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post code of the class? Most likely you have a name attribute with empty string assigned to it. Remove it completely and leave just the annotation tag @Entity.

Comment: @Entity
    @Table(name="properties")