# Hibernate @Entity Annotation

Tags: hibernate, jboss, annotations, entity

until today i Used the JBOSS Dev Studio 6.0. Now i upgraded to 7.0 and get a lot of Errors on the Hibernate Annotations. (Same Project works fine in 6.0)

I'm using `@Entity` without any further information. The Validator now says

```
The given name of the entity "path.to.ClassName" is empty JPA Problem
```

When i now modify the `@Entity` annotation to something like `@Entity(name="MyEntity")` The Problem is gone. Is this required now, or is it just a over sensitive Validation-Error that can be turned off without problems?

Strange:
When i import another Project, that is using `@Entity` as well, there is no Issue.
Also, when editing such an file and saving it, the error vanishes - until i select Maven -> Update the next time. Then the error comes up again. Seems like a bug to me?

Comment: try cleaning the project. alt+p n, its not any compilation issue, just something wrong with plugin.

Comment: cleaning eclipse does not resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I am working with Jboss Dev Studio 7 too and i am experimenting the same problem...
My entities seem to be right... when i start my jboss app server... the console has no error... I hide it turning off JPA Facet from my project settings. You could turn off the JPA validation instead.

For more information about this error you could reed this post:
[The given name of the entity "ClassName" is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675964/the-given-name-of-the-entity-classname-is-not-empty/21979815#21979815)